# Uploading theme on Wordpress on Microsoft Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure

I have a theme which needs to be uploaded on WordPress on Microsoft Azure. However, if I try to upload the ZIP file, I get a page saying

```
Are you sure you want to do this?

Please try again.
```

With 403 - Forbidden Error code

What is the error? How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to modify php.ini, i had the same issues but after trying I got it working.

### php ini

`upload_max_filesize = 256M`
`memory_limit = 128M`
`post_max_size = 80M`

### WP Memory Limit

IN FILE WP-CONFIG.PHP

`define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );`
`define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );`

### PHP Max Input Vars:

`max_input_vars = 3000;`

Comment: where is the php ini file?

Comment: The file is called `.user.ini` and you can find it in `App Service Editor`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a permission error -- you should check the privileges on wp-content/themes and make sure it is set to 0677. Furthermore, I'm not very familiar with Azure, but you should be able to check the error logs and get a more specific error message with additional details.

Comment: It's not a permissions thing in this case. Azure's default settings for a basic WordPress install don't give enough default memory or filesize limits for big items (images, themes, plugins, etc.).  So you have to edit the php vars to increase the limits.